# Need to filter, copy filtered, paste on 2nd tab, and delete the empty rows now on the first tab in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, delete-row

So first i need to filter which I have down already in the following code.  I then have to past that data onto the second tab. Then I must delete the empty rows from page 1 so that when I unfilter everything moves up so there won't be blanks in between. For the sake of not listing the company's info, I'll list the filter values as "S","T","U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" so that I won't list company info. I need to place to Sheets(Active Brands") cell A7

```
Sheets("Active Brands").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$O$993").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "S","T","U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to skip headers row

Try this:

```
With Worksheets("sheetNameToFilterAndCopyFrom")
    With .Range("$A$6:$O$993")
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "S","T","U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("sheetNameToPasteTo").Range("A7")destination:=Worksheets("sheetNameToPasteTo").Range("A7")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode=False
End With
```

Where you have to change "sheetNameToFilterAndCopyFrom" and "sheetNameToPasteTo" to your actual relevant worksheets names.

Comment: This worked beautifully for the filtering, copying and pasting of data. The one problem is that it also cut and paste my headers which are on row 6

Comment: I just changed the 6 to a 7 in the line With .Range("$A$6:$O$993")

Comment: One weird hiccup this is having is that it's moving the contents that should be on Sheet 1 Cell A7 to Sheet 2 Cell A7 even though it does not meet the criteria for information being pasted to the 2nd sheet.  Any thought as to why that might happen?

Comment: see edit post, since `Autofilter()` always get headers filtered you must offset the parent range by one row and resize it by the its rows number minus one to refer to parent range data only

Comment: Fine. Good coding!

Answer (score -1):

not sure of your proble, but if the issue is with this part "Then I must delete the empty rows from page 1 so that when I unfilter everything moves up so there won't be blanks in between. "

then use the following

```
Range("d3 or whatever your range is ").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

*xlCellTypeVisible = u can use many option here. like xlcelltype constant etc. Just F1 and see the option

Comment: That's part of it.  Basically I am unsure of how to specifically copy the filtered info from the first tab and copy it to the 2nd in vba.

Comment: Record the action and see what excel writes for you. EG at the top of the file `shift` + `end` key then `down arrow` selects to first record. So press the `shift` + `up arrow` to select the blank cells, then `shift` + `end` then `right arrow` to select all columns. Then cut, copy, paste. To record Alt + T, M, R, repeat to stop. Press Alt + F11 to see the code Excel wrote.